# How do I ping the Ubuntu host system from a Windows guest in VirtualBox?

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox, ping, ip-address

I connected to a wireless point and use "ifconfig" but I don't see any IP in eth0. Where's my IP address? Sorry if this is a silly question. :)

I want to use "ping" in Virtualbox Windows 7 guest. Which IP should I type in that machine?

[image: terminal IP info]

Comment: wlan0 > 192.168.1.198

Comment: when your are connected through wireless wlan0 will work , wlan mean wireless lan

Comment: check the ip address of windows 7 machine , ipconfig or by network adapter status

Comment: I want to ping Ubuntu from Windows 7 guest machine. Do I type "ping 192.168.1.198"?

Comment: 192.168.1.198 is the address of your ubuntu machine , for pinging you need to know the ip address of ubuntu machine & windows 7 machine , now u have ip address of ubuntu machine that is 192.168.1.198 & now u need to know the ip address  of windows 7 machine , How do u know ? , go to windows 7 machine and go to run type " cmd " & prompt will open , now type " ipconfig " then it will show you the ip of windows 7 machine , then ping it

Comment: from windows 7 , open prompt and type " ping 192.168.1.198 " its mean you are pinging ubuntu from windows 7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to get this is to just open up your connection information from the appindicator, like this:

[image: connection information]

That brings up your local IP address. Note that this isn't your IP address on the Internet, just your local address. You can always go to [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/) for an easy way to see it.

[image: IP info]

In your screenshot, eth0 is an Ethernet connection, and wlan0 is your wireless connection. To get your IP address in the Windows virtual machine, try typing `ipconfig/all` at a command prompt (Start/Accessories/Run/type 'CMD', and looking for your **default gateway** there:

[image: windows cmd prompt]

In this example, my guest sees the Ubuntu host as `10.0.2.2`
[image: windows pinging]

It may be that the VM sees it as a wired connection, even on a laptop with the host using wifi.

Comment: Very detailed! BTW thanks for editing my question title.